# implementing cas sever to use it on android

Tags: android, wsdl, server, cas

i've got a project and it's dealing with implementing CAS server(for user login with username and password) i have a document that contains an xml file and the company that has given me the project sent me an email but didn't exactly explain what to do they just explain some functions but i don't know how to use it on android should i parse this xml file for example?.this is the file which is called a wsdl if i'm right.i really appreciate your help guys i really need to do this in  3 or 4 days.thanks

Comment: :))))))))))) vaghaan awlie ke avalin search ino miare :))

Comment: @SiavashA dg che konim ma inim dg :)))

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to implement a custom CAS Server for using it on android. best way is

1. implement a sample CAS server
2. implement a login page in your android app and get credential
3. send username and password to CAS login url
4. validating ST Ticket to cas validate url

for doing these steps you can check requests parameters from a web CAS client.
[here](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CAS/Using+CAS+without+the+CAS+login+screen) is a helpful link.